# Show convergence of inner product of an operator and a weak convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

> Let $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq (W^{1,p}_0(\Omega))$, $u_n \rightharpoonup u \in (W^{1,p}_0(\Omega))$ and $B$ be an operator on $(W^{1,p}_0(\Omega))\times(W^{1,p}_0(\Omega))$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary.
>
> B is defined by $$\langle B(w,u), v\rangle := \int_\Omega ||\nabla u - h(w)||^{p-2}(\nabla u - h(w))\nabla v dx,$$ where $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and bounded and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle B(u_n, u_n), u_n - u \rangle \le 0$ holds.
>
> I want to show that $\langle B(u_n, v), u_n -u\rangle \to 0$ where $v\in (W^{1,p}_0(\Omega))$.

Is it right, that I just have to show that $B(u_n, v)\in(W^{1,p}_0(\Omega))^*$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Then the statement follows from the weak continuity of $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (?)

Comment: $\Omega$ is bounded, right? Because otherwise for $h(x)=1$ the integral defining $\left \langle B(w,u),v\right\rangle$ might fail to converge

Comment: Actually there is no information about $\Omega$ in my exercise.
But is my idea right? When $B(u_n, v)\in (W^{1,p}_0(\Omega ))^*$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $\langle B(u_n, v), u_n-u\rangle \to 0$?

Comment: No, it does not. You need some information on the map $u_n\mapsto B(u_n,v)$. A priori, it could be that this dependance makes the evaluation $\left \langle B(u_n,v),u_n-u\right\rangle$ blow-up even if $\left \langle F,u_n-u\right\rangle$ for all $F\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)^*$. I think you need to work on the specific expression of $B(w,v)$ here. I tried myself and was not able to solve it, probably because I don't know how to use the condition that $u,v\in W_0^{1,p}$ rather than just $W^{1,p}$. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Here is an idea: By using the compact embedding, you have strong convergence $u_n \to u$ in $L^q$ for some $q$. This may be enough to get also the strong convergence of $h(u_n) \to h(u)$ in $L^r$ for some $r$. Now, if the exponents fit together, this could give your desired conclusion.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa could you explain, why this doesn't work?
As $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ it holds that $\langle f, u_n - u\rangle \to 0$ $\forall f\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)^*$.
The problem is that $B(u_n,v)$ is not a fixed value? Can't you just say that $\langle B(u_m, v), u_n-u\rangle\to 0$ $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$.
And as $B(u_n, v)\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)^*$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ it holds that $|\langle B(u_m, v), u_n-u\rangle| <\infty$ $\forall m\in \mathbb{N}$. So $B(u_n, v)$ shouldn't affect the limit?

Comment: @gerw compact embedding works if $\Omega$ is bounded... also how do you deduce strong convergence of $h\circ u_n$ from the strong convergence of $u_n$? Don't you need stronger conditions  on $h$ such as Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: @gerw Why do we have a compact embedding? Sobolev embedding theorem gives me just a continuous embedding.

Comment: @user3766553 Yes the problem is that $B(u_n,v)$ changes with $n$. So this functional can get larger and larger, and if this growth exceeds the speed with which $u_n-u$ converges to $0$, you cannot conclude anything. This is why you need to work with the specific form of these functionals..

Comment: @user3766553: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem